# ASP.NET MVC 3 How to Save ViewModel data to multiple associated tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Just a standard precursor, I'm teaching myself to program via ASP.NET MVC 3, so my knowledge is basic and conceptually I'm open to better approaches to what I'm attempting to do.

So, here's what I'm trying to do:

I've created a ViewModel that gathers Company and User data. My intention is to save this data into two Domain Models , Company and User, where the **Id** in **Company** is the Foreign key in **User**. Further, I want to pass the necessary User data to create a Membership.

My issue is, now that I've moved past the basic strongly-typed Model associations found in basic ASP.NET MVC tutorials, I'm not sure how to sync everything up via HttpPost.

Here is my **ViewModel**:

```
public class SPCompanyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Domain Model for **Company** and **User**:

```
namespace BidFetcher.Models.ServiceProvider
{
public class SPCompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class SPUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SPCompanyId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
}
```

And here's my problem area, the **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SPCompanyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var spCompany = new SPCompany
        {
            CompanyName = viewModel.CompanyName,
        };
        db.SPCompany.Add(spCompany);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

As you can see, I'm able to create a Company record without issue. However, now I'm stuck because I'm not sure how to easily grab the Company **Id** from that record I just created so that I can create a new row in the User table.

Any code suggestions, or conceptual suggestions on tackling this sort of issue, are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use EF or ADO.net to read and write to DB?

Comment: I'm using basic code-first via EF.

Answer (score 1):

If your id is generated on sql server, you can add Attribute:
[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
and value of this Key will be in your Entity after db.SaveChanges()
Example:

```
public class SPCompany
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SPCompanyViewModel viewModel)
{
    var spCompany = new SPCompany
    {
        CompanyName = viewModel.CompanyName,
    };
    db.SPCompany.Add(spCompany);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var spCompanyId = spCompany.Id //there you get id of new record

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```